# Is there a story to guide my class choices for all 4e classes?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation

In the Dungeons & Dragons 4e red box (my starting point), there's this story that goes: if you could do {something}, your character is a {some class} - and that's how you make your character. The only problem is it's limited to only the main 4 classes and 4 races. I'm still quite new to the game and am wondering if anyone has made another story-based way to guide my choices for every class and race in 4e, guiding me to a particular class based on the story elements I'm after.

Comment: Ok first thing to simplify this is the reason I asked is because I'm lazy and have found that thedook bit I doesn't guide you to your class it helps you know what the modifiers are and what the basics are for your class here how about some quotes from the boo

Comment: Please slow down and try to ask your questions coherently. That last comment isn't understandable. Edit it as necessary.

Answer (score 10):

No. Only the Red Box provides that kind of character creation guidance.

Answer (score 2):

There's no unified list for every race and class in the game, as far as I am aware. However, the three Player's Handbooks each offer such guidance for the races and classes they contain, and other 4e manuals offering new races and base classes may do something similar.

The first Player's Handbook offers a description of what its races and classes do at the very beginning of *Chapter 2: Making Characters.* It explains the races contained within the book on page 14, and classes on page 15, which covers the basic four races and classes you've probably already read about, plus extras introduced in that book. The second and third Player's Handbooks offer a *brief* summary of each race and class on the opening page of their race and class chapters - though since the space on these pages is limited, these summaries can get *very* brief.

The very first page for each of the races and classes from all three Player's Handbooks will contain a slightly longer summary of their story elements and defining characteristics. You can use the briefer summary lists to make a shortlist of the races and classes you're interested in potentially playing, then check out these longer summaries to narrow down your list.